# Python: pyopenssl syntax error at import

Tags: python-requests

When calling the Requests package I get the following:

```
Traceback (most recent calls last)
  File "/storage/emulated/0/qpython/py-web-search-master/pws/google.py", line 6, in <module>
    import requests
  File "/data/data/org.qpython.qpy3/files/lib/python3.2/site-packages/requests/__init__.py", line 52, in <module>
    from .packages.urllib3.contrib import pyopenssl
  File "/data/data/org.qpython.qpy3/files/lib/python3.2/site-packages/requests/packages/urllib3/contrib/pyopenssl.py", line 169
    for prefix in [u'*.', u'.']:
                        ^
```

SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Could it be due to my system or the requests code?

Answer (score 0):

Python 3.2 not supported anymore.